# Why am I getting a nullReferenceException when creating a new DotNetNuke user via c#?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have the following code in my DotNetNuke module to register a new user:

```
protected static int RegisterNewDnnAccount(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password)
    {
        // Create user
        var user = new UserInfo();
        user.FirstName = firstName;
        user.LastName = lastName;
        user.Email = email;
        user.DisplayName = string.Concat(firstName, " ", lastName);
        user.Username = email;
        user.IsSuperUser = false;

        user.Profile.FirstName = firstName;
        user.Profile.LastName = lastName;
        user.Profile.PreferredTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        user.Profile.PreferredLocale = "en-US";
        user.Profile.Telephone = string.Empty;
        user.Profile.Cell = string.Empty;
        user.Profile.PostalCode = string.Empty;
        user.Profile.City = string.Empty;
        user.Profile.Street = string.Empty;
        user.Profile.Region = string.Empty;

        // Set up membership
        var membership = new UserMembership(user);
        membership.Approved = true;
        membership.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        membership.Password = password;
        membership.IsOnLine = false;
        user.Membership = membership;

        // Register the account
        var status = UserController.CreateUser(ref user);
        switch (status)
        {
            case UserCreateStatus.Success:
                return user.UserID;

            case UserCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to create user account: invalid password");

            case UserCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to create user account: Invalid email");

            case UserCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A user already exists with this email address");

            case UserCreateStatus.UserAlreadyRegistered:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This user is already registered");

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("user account creation failed for an unknown reason");
        }
    }
```

When the `UserController.CreateUser(ref user);` method gets called, DotNetNuke's API throws a`NullReferenceException`, with of course zero information on what is actually null.

I have verified that every one of the fields I set above are not null, so obviously it's something I'm NOT setting that is causing this issue.  Most of the properties I am setting were from me trying to get this  error to stop, which I have failed to do.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:** Here's the stack trace:

> at `DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.IsMemberOfPortalGroup(Int32 portalId)`
>      at `DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.AutoAssignUsersToRoles(UserInfo user, Int32 portalId)`
>      at `DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.CreateUser(UserInfo& user)`
>      at `PlayerOnDemand.Common.Utils.ClientUserUtils.RegisterNewDnnAccount(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password)` in C:\XOS\Projects\DNN\Website\DesktopModules\XOSDigital.PlayerOnDemand\PlayerOnDemand.Common\Utils\ClientUserUtils.cs:line 160

Comment: Don't you need to intialize Profile? user.Profile = new Profile() { //enter all the properties here };

Comment: No, it appears that creating a new `UserInfo` object automatically instantiates a membership and profile object

Comment: Stepping through this with the debugger should show you what's null.

Comment: It's not my code that's accessing a null object, it's DNN's code so I can't step throug hit

Comment: For situations like this, it's really helpful to unzip the source package of DNN over top of your dev site, so that you _can_ step through DNN's code and track down something like this a lot quicker.  You can also view DNN's code where it's doing something similar (i.e. check out who in the core code is calling `CreateUser`), and make sure you're doing everything they're doing.

Comment: Good point.  I guess I could easily enough extract the source into my local IIS where I"m running from.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  The issue was I wasn't explicitly setting the user's portal.

Answer (score 0):

Any exception in DNN which is 'object not set' and a stack trace reveals it to be either portalSettings or perhaps something like language is usually because, in the context of the call, there is no portalSettings object loaded into the current context.items collection.

This often happens when people generate emails or do other work in a scheduled call, which doesn't have the current request context loaded.

You may have to mock the current portalSettings object in a fake context in order to use parts of the DNN Api because of this issue.